# Get a query from url in php

Tags: php, geocoding

I don't know how to do this in php.  I am trying to get geocode data from openstreetmap.org but I need to do this in php.

In Javascript (and I have this working), it's:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=43.642018&lon=-79.374671">
</script>
```

I have that url but I don't know how to execute it in php.

I have tried:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=43.642018&lon=-79.374671";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

But this doesn't work.  I tried the same with curl.  Any ideas or is this type of query not possible in php?

Comment: is it generating any errors? on most servers they're in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: The first version includes a javascript from OpenStreetMap, but what are you trying to achieve with the second version? I think you need to be a bit more specific than "get geocode data".

Comment: All that URL returns for me is `<error>Unable to geocode</error>`

Comment: Sorry, the lat&lon I specified were examples.  I corrected the question to have a valid latitude and longitude.  You can try the url again

Comment: @JKirchartz, I do see an error "failed to open stream:  php_network_getaddresses:".  Could it be that our server is not configured to do this for php but is for javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this;

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=43.642018&lon=-79.374671");
 print_r($xml);
```

which will return you with an array of the values, see below;

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
     [@attributes] => Array
         (
            [timestamp] => Thu, 22 Mar 12 18:31:11 +0000
            [attribution] => Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.
            [querystring] => format=xml&lat=43.642018&lon=-79.374671
         )

[result] => 1, Yonge Street, Corktown, Toronto, Ontario, M5B2H1, Canada
[addressparts] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [house_number] => 1
        [road] => Yonge Street
        [suburb] => Corktown
        [city] => Toronto
        [county] => Toronto
        [state] => Ontario
        [postcode] => M5B2H1
        [country] => Canada
        [country_code] => ca
    )

 )
```

Then manipulate the data however you see fit.

Comment: This was the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does return

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<reversegeocode timestamp='Thu, 22 Mar 12 18:07:13 +0000' attribution='Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.' querystring='format=xml&amp;lat=100&amp;Lon=100'>
<error>Unable to geocode</error></reversegeocode>
```

That just means that there is no address for that particular coordinate.. This however has
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=100

Read [API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) if you need more details

Comment: Sorry, the lat&lon I originally specified were examples.  I corrected the question to have a valid latitude and longitude.  It looks like my $response is null.

Comment: Works for me. Shows Toronto info. You must be having DNS problems, or if you are using shared hosting then its forbidden on server